# Sort an array by reversing the substrings only, find the min steps

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

Given a list of integers, the only operation that can be done on the list is to reverse the sub list of the list.
Q: what's the minimal operation to sort the list?

For example,

For 3, 2, 1, it's 1 since only one reverse on the whole list is needed.
For 3, 1, 2, it's 2. First reverse (1, 2), so the list becomes (3, 2, 1). Then reverse the whole list.

I've tried the following C# code but it doesn't work.

```cs
FindMin(arr, 0);
// return minSteps;

static int minSteps = int.MaxValue;
static HashSet<(int i0, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7)> tried = 
    new HashSet<(int i0, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7)>();

static void FindMin(int[] arr, int level)
{
    if (IsAscending(arr)) 
    {
        minSteps = Math.Min(minSteps, level);
        return;
    }
    var x = (GetItem(arr, 0), GetItem(arr, 1), GetItem(arr, 2), GetItem(arr, 3), GetItem(arr, 4), GetItem(arr, 5), GetItem(arr, 6), GetItem(arr, 7));
    if (tried.Contains(x)) return;
    tried.Add(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 2; j < arr.Length + 1; j++)
        {
            var l = arr[0..i].Concat(arr[i..j].Reverse()).Concat(arr[j..]).ToArray();
            FindMin(l, level + 1);
        }
    }
}

static int GetItem(int[] arr, int i)
{
    return (arr.Length > i) ? arr[i] : 0;
}

private static bool IsAscending(int[] arr)
{
    var pre = arr[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < pre) return false;
        pre = arr[i];
    }
    return true;
}
```

How to calculate the time complexity of the function? How to improve it?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done using dynamic programming. But I haven't figured out the sub-problem.

Comment: If the question is "what is the minimal number" does that mean we are not required to show the steps, but only to calculate the number?

Comment: I can offer O(n^2) solution, not sure if the sorting is done in minimum amount of steps but I haven't found a counter-example yet, also it's not done with dynamic programming

Comment: @Dialecticus, yes, it doesn't require to show the steps. Only the number.

Comment: @Ecto, how you did it in O(N^2)?

Comment: @ca9163d9 Take a peek, it might be similar to yours solution... https://textuploader.com/1qz4c  let me know what do you think about it

Comment: @Ecto, given an array of  `5, 4, 3, 1, 2`, it can take two operations `1, 2` to `2, 1`, and then reverse the whole array. It seems your code will take more than 2?

Comment: yep, true, my code doesn't find the minimum amount of steps then, I will think of something else

Comment: I was thinking about grouping items, that are in correct order (not necessarily position) and also remembering, if they are in the right order (ascending or descending). Then sort them (whole groups only) in similar fashion, but in every rotation, ascending changes to descending etc, and finally change all descending groups into ascending (if their size is >1). Maybe something to think about